# Insecure HTTP connections are disabled by default on iOS and Android Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, http

I need to allow all HTTP for all requests in my code.

The code works fine in debug and release mode for the apk, but it doesn't work when I upload it to Google play as bundle.aab

1- I created network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

2- add to AndroidManifest/application

```
 <application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
......
  >
```

3- add meta-data to application

```
<application 
......>
.....
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
 android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
 </application>
```

4- add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should https but if you still want to use http protocol then add the following to your Info.plist file in iOS:

```js
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Also  for android add this entry in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```js
<application
  ...
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
  ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it any specific domain you are trying to call?

You can try adding the `<domain-config>` tag, if you know which domain you might be using. There is a section on Android documentation, if you want to force the system to use only secure connections [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted).

But you can try changing some values in that to see if disabling those force items can solve your problem.

Try something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">network.domain.com</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But this is only for Android.

Comment: Already I tried this mydomin.com

Comment: Can you explain what error code or error you are getting when you are trying to call the unsecured url? Also can you share that unsecured url?

Comment: I can't see the errors because it crashes when I upload it to the store only for the Android internal test. It works fine on IOS

Comment: Do you get any errors from the Play Store when it's not uploading your bundle file?

Comment: I uploaded it ( internal test ) when I installed it on my mobile, it is working, but the APIs are not

Comment: I suggest you to use some kind of logger to see and understand the issue. You can implement some online system like analytics to log your errors or you can also use some local logger system like "flutter_logs" https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_logs.
This will help you in getting some error message or codes which can be helpful in solving the problem.